Splitting values in a cell
I have some cells which contain multiple values are per the screenshot:

Is there an easy way to split these values into individual columns? So "Sales and Clearance" would be in one column, and "Suspension > Front Axle > Front Axle Bushes" would be in the next?
They range from 1 to 5 values in each cell.

Do you only have 2 row in your table?

Hi go into advanced editor get these values into rows. Right-click on the column and select below option.

and pick below option

give the option > as below and click okay


Thanks for the reply.. It doesn't quite work in this case (unless I've missed something). That splits the values where there is only 1 line. In the screenshot, the cell labelled "Table", has multiple values in it which I'm trying to spit. Where I've pointed the green arrow as an example

Can you show me what is the icon on the top of the column look like? You have to expand the column from table format to column format. In your case since column contains strings and tables fist filter tables and then expand them.
